# Possible summation of numbers with different signs

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory

Given $n$ numbers $x_i,i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, define the set of all possible summation of $x_i$ with different signs:
$$Y = \{\sum_i x_i s_i : s_i = \pm 1\}.$$

What can we say about the set $Y$? I remember there are some results connect to this question, but I don't remember the keywords of the results.

Comment: This is not exactly the same problem, but might give a good starting point for searching the literature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Some simple observations: $Y$ consists if at most $2^{n}$ points in $[-\sum |x_i|,\sum |x_i|]$; the average of these numbers is $0$ and the end points $\pm \sum |x_i|$ belong to $Y$.

Comment: One can alternatively study $Z = \{ \sum_i x_i u_i : u_i \in \{0, 1 \} \}$, which i s related to $Y$ by a simple scaling.

Comment: Also, $|Y| = 2^n$ is achievable, for example with $x_i = 2^i$ (then this is basically the fact that binary expansions are unique).